# Change the database path for a Crystal Report dynamically through C# code when the form with the report viewer loads

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, crystal-reports

I have a simple application that connects to an Access database (.mdb). I connected the database file to the application using code only. The connection string is as follows,

**"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\CentreDB.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=pass"**

For designing purposes I connected the database file to a crystal report by using the Connect Database File option in the report Wizard. But I need to use code to dynamically assign the database to the crystal report, so that I wont have a problem when I deploy it in a client machine. I tried to use this code below.

```
public void ViewReport(FileInfo crFileInfo) // path\filename.rpt
        {
            ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
            crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "YOUR SERVER NAME";
            crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "YOUR DATABASE NAME";
            crConnectionInfo.UserID = "YOUR DATABASE USERNAME";
            crConnectionInfo.Password = "YOUR DATABASE PASSWORD";

            // CrystalReportViewer control
            crViewer.ReportSource = ReportSourceSetup(crFileInfo, crConnectionInfo);
            crViewer.Refresh();
        }

        ReportDocument ReportSourceSetup(FileInfo crFileInfo, ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo)
        {
            ReportDocument crDoc = new ReportDocument();
            TableLogOnInfos crTableLogonInfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
            TableLogOnInfo crTableLogonInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
            Tables crTables;

            crDoc.Load(crFileInfo.FullName);

            // Each table in report needs to have logoninfo setup:
            crTables = crDoc.Database.Tables;
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table crTable in crTables)
            {
                crTableLogonInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
                crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogonInfo);
            }

            return crDoc;
        }
```

I found this sample on the net, but I can't get it to work. I need to know where I need to place this exactly & what I should pass for "YOUR SERVER NAME", "YOUR DATABASE NAME" since I'm using a database file with only a password. I think that the FileInfo object carries the path of the database. Please help me if possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With access I believe you should specify a DSN as the servername, so setup a DSN on the machine and reference it this way...if you named the dsn access_dsn:

```
        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "access_dsn"; //dsn name
        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = ""; //leave blank, it knows from DSN
        crConnectionInfo.UserID = "YOUR DATABASE USERNAME";
        crConnectionInfo.Password = "YOUR DATABASE PASSWORD";
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but then still I will have to go to the client machine & manually create a DSN for the access database depending on the location I deploy the application. Isn't there any other way. Please forgive me for my incompetence, I'm new to programming.

Comment: A DSN is only a few registry entries. If you're going to create an installer app for your access db then it should be fairly straight forward to include these registry entries in the installer and have it setup the DSN for you on install. I've done this before using Inno Setup compiler and it worked wonders (I also got it to install the required drivers for the ODBC DSN)